# Embedding a Python Game In a Web Site

Tags: python

So I have finished my first game in Python.  Now I want to know if I can embed it on my site.  Do I have to add more code or is it not possible.  When I say embed I mean have the actual game in the web browser. 
Thanks!

Comment: Is this a text-only sort of game?

Comment: What framework did you write your game with?

Comment: That kind of depends of how you made the game. Is it GUI-based? In that case, I think it's impossible.

Answer (score 3):

**2021 Update:**

https://anvil.works/python-browser one-stop shop for hosting Python in browser

https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide  compile Python to Javascript, then run in browser

https://brython.info  full access to Javascript DOM from Python

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Skulpt](http://skulpt.org)?

Looks like it takes a bit of infrastructure to get it going, but it seems as if it might be what you are looking for.

Of course, I don't know if it supports more than just Turtle. Haven't looked too deeply into it, myself.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168588/can-python-be-embedded-in-html-like-php-and-jsp) should help. I haven't ever tried doing this on my page, but it could be interesting. This link includes several ways to put it into HTML. It uses templates, so it may be easier. Good luck!